# Remove a wishlist item from a customers session

Tags: php, magento-enterprise, magento-1, wishlist

I'm creating an Ajax Handler where one of the methods is removing an item from the wishlist.

I know how to add a product to the wishlist:

```
$wishlist = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());

if ($wishlist->addNewItem($product)) {
  $wishlist->save();
  $result['result']=true;
  $result['count']=$wishlist->getItemsCount();
}
```

I just can't find the functionality relating to removing the item from the wishlist.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$product_id = "ur id";
$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer_id);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();
foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
    $w_product_id = $item->getProductId();
    if (in_array($w_product_id, $product_id)) {
        $item->delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$item = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item');
$item->loadWithOptions($itemId); // You wishlist item id
$item->delete();
```